# Rails many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

I have implemented a save buttons for jobs and it work fine now i want to list some of the saved jobs in the jobs index page for this i have this code

```
<h3>Saved Jobs</h3>
<ul>
<% @user.saved_jobs.limit(5).order(:created_at).reverse_order.each do |saved_job| %>
<li><%= link_to saved_job.job.title, saved_job.job.url %>
<span class="delete_button">    
<%= link_to "X", saved_job, :method => :delete, :remote => true %></span></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<%= link_to "see all", saved_jobs_path %>
```

but when i want access to the jobs index page i get this error `undefined method` `saved_jobs' for nil:NilClass`

this my saved_jobs controller

```
class SavedJobsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @saved_jobs = SavedJob.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id) 
    end

    def create
        @job = Job.find(params[:saved_job][:job_id])
        current_user.save_job!(@job)

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @job }
            format.js
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @job = SavedJob.find(params[:id]).job
        current_user.saved_jobs.find(params[:id]).destroy

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @job }
            format.js
        end
    end

end
```

and this is my user controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!


  def show
    @user = User.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    if @user
      @posts = Post.all
      render action: :show
    else
      render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end
  end


  def index
    @users = user_scope.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2)
  end 

  private

  def user_scope
    current_user ? User.where.not(id: current_user.id) : User.all
  end

end
```

Comment: your `@user` variable seems to equal nil, also you could/should move `.saved_jobs.limit(5).order(:created_at).reverse_order.each do |saved_job|` to your controller, also instead of ordering by created_at and reversing order, you could use descending order. you should create a scope that could be reused. in your view you should only see `@user_jobs.each`

Comment: which controller and action is rendering the view you posted?

Comment: The saved_jobs controller

Comment: yes but it didn't work

Comment: happy to help if you describe the new error

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you didn't set @user in your controller action. Can you post the code from your controller?

Update based on controller code:

Your index action in SavedJobsController does not set @user. When you then call `@user.saved_jobs.limit(5)..etc...` in the view @user is nil, rather than current_user or whatever.

Additionally, you have set @saved_jobs - why not just use that instead of @user.saved_jobs?

for instance:

```
#in SavedJobsController
def index
  @saved_jobs = current_user.saved_jobs.limit(5).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

and then, in your view:
`<% @saved_jobs.each do |saved_job| %>`

Comment: thanks for your help now it work i have change the code to this <% @current_user.saved_jobs.each do |saved_job| %>

Comment: glad it's working. Probably you mean `current_user` rather than `@current_user`?  In either case, the rails convention in the index action of the SavedJobsController is to set an instance variable to hold the collection of corresponding objects (e.g., @saved_jobs in this case), and then to use that in the corresponding view. So, if you want `current_user.saved_jobs` then assign that to @saved_jobs in the controller and use `@saved_jobs.each do |saved_job|`in the view. The goal is to make the views as logic-less as possible.

Comment: yes this is what you have suggested in your answer but it didn't work it give me the same error msg